# Android - Temporal & Ancestral Navigation with ViewPager & Fragments

Tags: android, navigation, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to work out the best way to implement the 'ancestral' and 'temporal' navigation (utilising the up button and back buttons), for a music player I'm working on.

Currently, the user is presented with a viewpager, and can page between three main fragments (ArtistMain, AlbumMain and SongMain). Upon choosing an item inside that view, a fragment transaction occurs, and the viewpager goes out of view, replaced by a new fragment (AlbumSub, Songsub or player, depending on where the user came from). The user can then navigate deeper, until a song is chosen, and then they are taken to the 'player' screen.

I guess the question is: **How do I implement all of this conditional navigation?**

I'm fairly new to android and programming in general, and I just can't seem to come up with an efficient way to achieve this. At the moment, as each fragment is brought into view, the app is checking to see where the user just came from, and then determines where the user should be taken if back or home is called. This means I have a booleans like "fromArtistMain", "fromAlbumSub", and I'm checking for things like "fromSongSub && fromPlayer".. it's all turning into a bit of a mess.

I've drawn a diagram (in paint, sorry!!), to depict the navigation I'm trying to achieve. The yellow represents the 'up' button press, the red is the 'back' button press, and blue is just normal navigation. The green arrows are meant to represent the view paging:

[image: Navigation Diagram]

Any advice is welcome. It might take something really simple that I've just overlooked.

Thanks for your time.

Edit:

I have been adding fragments to the backstack, and using popBackStack() calls, the problem is that popping the backstack is not necessarily the correct option in each case.

I've currently got a whole mess of code trying to determine whether a transaction should be added to the backstack in the first place.

Consider the following:
User chooses a song straight from 'SongMain', and is taken to 'Player'. Now using the home button should (in my mind), take the user to SongSub (the list of songs from the album that the chosen song belongs to). Now if the user navigates up again, they will be taken to 'AlbumSub', the list of Albums by that artist. This is a fragment transaction, but adding to the backstack would mean the user would be taken down a level on back press (which I think would be unexpected). So in this case I don't add that particular transaction to the backstack - seems fine, but there are quite a few different cases, and combined with a viewpager at the top which needs to come in and out of visibility, the code gets really messy.

All of this means a whole bunch of conditionals determining where the user came from and which path they took to get there..

Would it be wise to have a bunch of booleans in the host activity which get set depending on where the user has navigated, and then checking those booleans to see if a transaction should be added tot he backstack? This is kind of what I already have, but it seems really inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking into is called the `Back stack`. You can read more about it here at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

If you use a single Activity to host each of these Fragments then you can modify your code to explicity add your Fragments to the Fragment Back stack using code like so:

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();       
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);      
    transaction.addToBackStack("NameOfFragment");
    transaction.commit();
```

So, if you do the above code with Fragments like so:

```
Fragment1 -> Fragment2 -> Fragment3 -> Fragment4
```

Then from `Fragment4` if you call this method:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

Then `Fragment4` will be finished and `Fragment3` will restart. Simple. You can have this line called from a button click or you can override the behaviour of the back button to call it.

*Please note in the examples I've used the function `getSupportFragmentManager()` which is a method name in the Compatibility Package. If you're not using the Compatibility Package then you can instead call `getFragmentManager()`.*

**EDIT**

The problem with the navigation you envisage is that breaking out of the backstack paradigm half way through means that your app will "Act Differently" than the rest of the OS. This is by and large discouraged by Google. But then again, saying that, I do exactly the same in my app for very similar reasons :).

When you navigate "up", along one of your yellow lines, you are following a discrete link (so, `startActivity(new Intent(this, SongSub));` or whatever) and you want this to "break" the backstack.

It's at this stage you can make a decision about how you want to go forward:

- You can start a Task (backstack) using SongSub as 0th item. This is from memory what the Google Music app does and you're right, it's annoying. When you press back it should technically exit the app. Yuk. IMO if you're in an obvious page hierarchy, back should always navigate down the hierarchy over exiting the app.
- You can start a new Task using ArtistMain as the 0th element and layer fragments discretely ontop before `commit`ing your transaction, in effect creating a new backstack each time you go "up" rather than "back" (your backstack would now be ArtistMain->ArtistSub->SongSub). This is what I think your trying to ask here. It's possible but it's messy.
- You can create a more linear structure (probably the best idea if possible). Ignore the backstack paradigm, make "back" and "up" **always** go up a level no matter where you came from (Player always goes to SongSub, SongSub always goes to AlbumSub). This will give the user the least confusing and most transparent (as well as easiest to implement) experience - the user will learn quickly how to navigate (and how many "backs" to press) to get to where they want to be.

Comment: thanks for your response. Please see my edits - This doesn't really answer the question for me (I'm already using the fragmentManager backstack).